# How to update only exact value matches?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

I am using SQL update query [in powershell script] to update machine name present in column.

The column values are stored as URL. So machine name is part of the string.

( Column Name : URL
Example column value : "http://Machine1:80/Impl100/Core/Data/Config.0")

I am using following query to do the update.

```
$UpdateQuery="UPDATE [$DatabaseName].[dbo].[$TableName] 
SET $columnName=Replace("$ColumnName", '$OldMachineName', '$NewMachineName');"
```

Assume my old machine name is "Machine1" and i am to replace with "AppMachine1". If i execute the script ,it will update "AppMachine1". But if i execute the script second time It will update it as "AppAppMachine1" as Machine1 is part of AppMachine1.

Is it possible to get the column value and check the machine name before update?

How to do this?

Comment: replace with a more heavily anchored token? `'//AppMachine1:'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$UpdateQuery="UPDATE [$DatabaseName].[dbo].[$TableName] 
SET $columnName=Replace("$ColumnName", '$OldMachineName', '$NewMachineName')
WHERE "$ColumnName" <> '$NewMachineName';"
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the double leading forward slashes:

```
 ... -replace '//machine1','//AppAppMachine1'
```

You also need to put quoted variables in double quotes. Single quotes disables variable expansion and as a result variables will no be replaced with its values.

Here's an example of a double replace:

```
PS> $url = 'http://machine1:80/Impl100/Core/Data/Config.0'
PS> $url -replace '//machine1','//AppAppMachine1' -replace '//machine1','//AppAppMachine1'

http://AppAppMachine1:80/Impl100/Core/Data/Config.0
```

Comment: in this case if the machine is changed at trialing characters then it will fail. For ex. If machine name is replaced Machine123 then if we execute second time it will be //Machine1231

Comment: Oops, I added the double slashes to the replacement string.